# In app billing on android, supported markets and different APKs for different countries?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, apk

I'm trying to implement in-app billing in my android app and had a few questions:

Where can I see a list of countries which allow in-app billing in android apps?

Can I upload different APKs for different countries, so only countries which allow in-app billing get the game with in-app billing built-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of all countries that allow in-app billing is here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138294?hl=en

Different APKs for the same app can be uploaded for different countries, but the package name must change for each one.  The developer then needs to limit distribution by country for the non-in-app-enabled APK.